# Can't login through wp-login.php on fresh installation

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I have currently installed a fresh Wordpress on a dedicated server. It's the latest version with no plugins at all. Everything went successfully as always, I can see the website, but when I try to login through wp-login.php, no matter right or wrong data I'm inputting in the login form I receive "402 Payment Required" error! And a blank page, no reaction at all.

I'm checking server logs and there is no any php error either. 
I want to note that wp-login.php is not corrupt and is working, change password functionality which is part of that page is fully working.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any plugins? That error code is really weird. You can turn on debugging in Wordpress with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: Thanks Tomas for your response! No there are no plugins! this is a brand new WordPress installation, nothing is changed. Wp_Debug does not show any warning at all. So there can't be any bugs here, as it's a clear new wordpress setup. This is something definitely connected with server configuration. I'll try inline debugging.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I had the same problem with a customers site when they moved to a dedicated server. It turned out the host had added some mod_security rules into WHM.

Comment: Thank you Darren! Playing with mod_security had fixed the problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We've installed mod_security php module and it had fixed the problem.

Comment: Bizarrely enabling and then disabling mod_security for my domain resolved this issue for me. Keeping it enabled resulted in the the 402 error persisting.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this issue comes from the servers. If you use weak password for an example, if you use "admin" as a password. Then server want be allowed you to login, you will be blocked by the firewall. So as a option try to use strong password.